# Python arrays is not working

Tags: python, arrays

> x = [1,2,3],[2,3,4]

`x=array(x)` is not working in python. 
It shows array is not defined.

Comment: use `x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: Python has `list` not `array`

Comment: What do you expect `array` to do?

Comment: I expect this to work `x=array(x)` @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: What do you *expect it to do*? Obviously you expected it to "work", but why would you imagine that this would be defined? Did you read about it in the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation. I need to import an array module from python library. I have a problem with 2D arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array` is a module in the standard library, you must import it before you can use it.

```
from array import array
x = 1, 2, 3
x = array('i', x)
x
```

#### output:

```
array('i', [1, 2, 3])
```

Please read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), arrays require to declare the type of objects it contains.

#### alternative 1: use list

In your case, you may want to use list instead. lists are collections of objects that can be of any type:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]   # list of integers
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]   # list of lists of integers
x = ['a', 1, 3.14]  # list of various objects
```

#### alternative 2: use numpy array

numpy is an external library that must be installed separately.

```
import numpy
x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This code worked for me `from array import array
x = 1, 2, 3
x = array('i', x)
x` But what if I want to use x as nested arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as stated in the comments by *abccd*, python has `list` not `array` by default.
So, you'll be getting an error like
 `name array was not defined`

But if you are planning to use `array` then I guess what you are trying to do is use numpy.array

Here is the code that you want:

```
from numpy import array
x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
x = array(x)
```

This will store a `numpy array` in x, which will let you handle it in an easier way than the usual lists.

Comment: Not the surrounding brackets in `x` - you are first defining a List of Lists.  Then `numpy.array` converts that LoL into an array.  One difference between lists & arrays is that lists can hold any type of object, while I believe arrays can hold only numbers.  In addition, numpy arrays can do array math between arrays (eg. `array1 * array2`), while lists must be iterated to do the same thing (eg. `for x in MyList: ...`).

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: Python does have arrays. It stores the array as an object. I have asked the question how to use it using python array, not numpy one.

Comment: I believe what you want to say is a 'list', not an 'array'